# Wired, Light up, Keyboard with chiclet keys and no internet

Tags: keyboards

What keyboards exist that meet these specifications?:

1. Can't connect to the internet, even with a program.(Some keyboards require an internet connection or a configuration program that requires one.)
2. Does not have any type of padding that can come off from wear and tear or otherwise(I.e. dirt and glue won't be exposed from loose padding).
3. Is not wireless.
4. The keys light up.
5. Has chiclet keys(keys are lower and easier to reach than a normal keyboard) with space between the keys for easy cleaning.
6. Will endure a lot of use.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider a gaming keyboard, because they can take quite a bit of abuse and wear.

[image]

The [Razer Deathstalker](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA4RE4TS1920&cm_re=razer_deathstalker-_-9SIA4RE4TS1920-_-Product) is the first keyboard that comes to mind meeting your specifications, being a wired chiclet keyboard with backlighting. The keyboard also has anti-ghosting capabilities which helps prevent mis-types. If you want to maximize your price point, you could also consider the [non-back lit variant](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA1JX5290367&cm_re=razer_deathstalker-_-9SIA1JX5290367-_-Product).

Comment: I appreciate the response but Razer products generally violate specification #1, which would include the specific product mentioned. I added specification #1 specifically because of Razer. The mentioned product does however meet every other criteria.

Comment: What's so bad about the keyboard connecting to the internet through a software package? If you're concerned about some tracking issues you could choose to deliberately not install the software controller. Then the keyboard wouldn't "connect to the internet" unless you count your OS checking for new drivers for your keyboard.

Comment: You won't really find anything else out there.

Comment: I have this keyboard and I'm 99% sure it doesn't connect to the internet. In fact, the lights work very well without the internet and you can configure them offline (will check that again when I get home).